# Adding a JOIN to this mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT t1.* FROM HOSTS AS t1
WHERE
t1.BOSS = 'BRUCE'
OR ( t1.BOSS_TYPE = 'manager'
 AND t1.BOSS_ID = 'BRUCE' )
OR t1.BOSS IN ( SELECT t2.STORES FROM
  FOLLOW_STORES AS t2 
 WHERE t2.BOSSES = 'BRUCE' )
```

The above query works great, but i want to add a JOIN to get extra information

I want to add this JOIN but i cant get it to work. I must be inserting it in the wrong place.

```
 JOIN MANAGER_POSTS AS t3 ON ( t1.POSTER_ID = t3.POSTER_ID
    AND t1.SUBMISSION_TYPE =  'post' )
```

What is the correct way to add the join to get this extra information

Comment: JOIN usually goes before WHERE. please post full query you are using.

Comment: thank you that worked, post that so i can accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here try this one:

```
SELECT  t1.* , t3.*
FROM    HOSTS AS t1 
            INNER JOIN MANAGER_POSTS AS t3 
                ON ( t1.POSTER_ID = t3.POSTER_ID AND 
                     t1.SUBMISSION_TYPE =  'post' )
WHERE   t1.BOSS = 'BRUCE' 
        OR (t1.BOSS_TYPE = 'manager' AND t1.BOSS_ID = 'BRUCE' )
        OR t1.BOSS IN   ( 
                            SELECT t2.STORES 
                            FROM FOLLOW_STORES AS t2 
                            WHERE t2.BOSSES = 'BRUCE' 
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add your `JOIN` clause after your `FROM Hosts` and before your `WHERE`

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM HOSTS AS t1
INNER JOIN MANAGER_POSTS AS t3 
    ON ( t1.POSTER_ID = t3.POSTER_ID
    AND t1.SUBMISSION_TYPE =  'post' )
WHERE t1.BOSS = 'BRUCE'
    OR ( t1.BOSS_TYPE = 'manager'
          AND t1.BOSS_ID = 'BRUCE' )
    OR t1.BOSS IN ( SELECT t2.STORES 
                    FROM FOLLOW_STORES AS t2 
                    WHERE t2.BOSSES = 'BRUCE' )
```